# Python - comtypes (working) vs. pywin32 (not working) - Using python to create outlook rules

Tags: python, outlook, com, pywin32, comtypes

(Windows 10, Office 365, Python 3.7, Pycharm)

I am being able to successfully create a rule in outlook using comtypes:

```
import comtypes.client

o = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
rules = o.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
oRule = rules.Create("Test_Rule", 0)

condition = oRule.Conditions

oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From
oFromCondition.Enabled = True
oFromCondition.Recipients.Add("john@email.com")
oFromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll

condition.Enabled = True
root_folder = o.GetNamespace('MAPI').Folders['x@outlook.at']
dest_folder = root_folder.Folders["Posteingang"]

move = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
move.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Enabled(True)
move.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Folder(dest_folder)

rules.Save()
```

I am not being able to make it work using pywin32. When i run the following code, I get an error and the rule cannot be created:

```
import win32com.client as win32

o = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

caiok = o.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders['x@outlook.at']

dest_folder = caiok.Folders["Posteingang"]
colRules = o.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
oRule = colRules.Create("New Rule10", 0)

oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From
oFromCondition.Enabled = True
oFromCondition.Recipients.Add("john@email.com")
oFromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll

oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
oMoveRuleAction.Enabled=True
oMoveRuleAction.Folder=dest_folder

colRules.Save()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/wwo/scrapbookIII.py", line 20, in <module>
    colRules.Save()
  File "<COMObject GetRules>", line 2, in Save
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Mindestens eine Regel kann aufgrund von ungültigen Aktionen oder Bedingungen nicht gespeichert werden.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Python requires parens to call a function.  So, this does nothing:

```
oFromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll
```

You need:

```
oFromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll()
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for the input, but in the working example I didn't need the brackets.